# Licensing of software in commercial Youtube videos

Tags: licensing, software

I'm thinking of recording a couple of coding tutorials on Youtube. I wonder if I can use free (e.g. codepen) and purchased software (e.g. Visual Studio) in those videos without risking to run into licensing issues. And does it make a difference if those videos would be used for monetization purposes later on?

Comment: How will that software feature in your video's? Do you explain how to use the software, or is it merely shown as "I need a text editor to show the code itself and this has proper syntax highlighting"? That can play a role in if you could qualify for a Fair Use exemption.

Comment: Commercial, and monetisation is irrelevant: Read the free-software and open-source definitions.(the free-software definition is the easier to understand, and they both say mostly the same thing)